# What kind of tools could I use for some aluminum body finishing work without doing any cutting?

Tags: car, tools

I got into a really bad wreck last winter. My power steering was leaking and had locked up in the middle of an icy road, while I was trying to find a median at night. The guy hit me going around 70 miles an hour but I was able to redirect the momentum and ended up repairing it and redoing my front end as well. I had to replace the trailing arm, upper control arm and beat the dent out with a 2x4, car jack, and a big hammer, with some coolant hoses to spread the force evenly when using the car jack.  I smoothed it out most of the way by heating it with a propane torch and having someone hold a plate on the other side while i flattened it with the hammer. There's a lot to learn when it comes to undoing a collision but I've never really understood what a body puller does and I was wondering if anybody knows what kind of tools I might be able to get access to finish the job on my own.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What aluminum are you talking about? Last time I checked, aluminum doesn't rust. As for the question, looks like you have a good start on getting it fixed, but realistically, getting a replacement quarter is a much more realistic option as you'll spend way more time repairing this by using the hammer/dolly method, than you would by cutting the old off and welding a replacement in place. Just saying.

Comment: Judging by the activity in other questions, this guy's trolling: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/14899/how-do-i-fill-my-headlight-fluid-and-reiterate-my-sprocket-valve ,  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/14900/675

Comment: So are you saying that's a steel body? I never really thought of that. Anyways as far as I've gotten I'm worried that cutting and rewelding may cause a weakness or lead to other problems. I'm talking about the crease around the top of the brake light. There's also a spot along the body seam refer to first picture, that I didn't spend enough time on. Are there any machines that can do that kind of detailed reshaping? Something that small? Because they sure should make one. Something mounted to a track that could swivel and swing into different small areas, maybe using friction for heating sourc

Comment: The panel goes over the door and makes up the rest of the door frame, stopping at the side mirror. How hard would it be to remove that. I know there are spot welds in the back that could be drilled out. But how is that door frame held in place? I know it can't just be adhesive. It's a 1998 Civic EX.

Comment: You only cut away and replace what you need. If you have no experience with this type of work, you should leave it to a professional. In this case, though, it would be cut to match and butt welded to mate, then welds ground down to leave the metal flawless. Then you put a thin (very thin) coat of body putty over it to ensure the entire surface looks like new. If you have to put more than an 1/8" of body putty on it, you still have some metal work to do. You only use it to get rid of the high spots. Lots of fun: lots of work.

Answer (score 1):

Short strand fibreglass and Bondo would be the easiest option for you, I bet.

Alternatively, use a dolly and hammer. On top of that you can use a shrink disc from [Wolfes Metal](http://www.wolfesmetalfabrication.com/sdisc.html).

Comment: I really like the shrink disc method video.  Nice trick.